# Clarification on order of transformations

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose I have two rigid bodies, B1 and B2, I have the position of B2 relative to B1 as a standard homogenous transformation T_12 Similarly I the transformation of B1 relative to the origin as T_01.

When I want to compute the location of B2 relative to the origin, which order do I multiply the matriies?

Comment: could this https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/rotations/kinematics_rotation.html help? And the links therein at the top of the page "successive rotations". Then you only need to combine rotations with translations if needed

Comment: use this notation $~B_{20}=B_{21}\,B_{10}~$ (B from 2 to 0)  "1" cancel  .

$B_{12}=B_{10}\,B_{02}=  B_{10}\,B_{20}^T~$

Comment: Yeah thanks, it was pretty easy in retrospect .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way transforms are talked about is a bit confusing and I was having a brain fart over it. The key idea is the transform from A to B coordinate system wise is the transform that takes points written in B to be written in A.

To answer my question it's $T_{01}T_{12}$